# SmartLifecycleRoleController get status

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to get the status of the endpoints annotated with @Role that we can start / stop with the SmartLifecycleRoleController?

There doesn't seem to be a method for that, should we use another controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently supported; you'd have to use reflection to get a reference to the `lifecycles` map and iterate over it.

Or you could subclass it and declare it as a bean with name `IntegrationContextUtils.INTEGRATION_LIFECYCLE_ROLE_CONTROLLER` and intercept all the add calls.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4236) to provide access.

Comment: We actually found the solution of replacing the bean with our implementation a few minutes ago and it's working even if it's not perfect. I see that you already started on implementing the feature, thanks a lot.